# Adding external JARs to OpenJDK

Tags: java, jar, classpath

So far I know where I have to add external JARs to the traditional Java folder.

x64: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\my_jar.jar`

But in case of OpenJDK it is not the same. I can't get where I do have to put my external jars.

`C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-12.0.2.10-hotspot\lib` doesn't work.

Creating a `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-12.0.2.10-hotspot\jre\lib` doesn't work.

Error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Comment: This was never a recommended practice.  You should specify a classpath when you run your program.

Comment: I think you mean that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\my_jar.jar` worked. This functionality was deprecated with Java 8 and removed with Java 9 IIRC. You should explicitly specify your classpath instead.

Answer (score -1):

I am glad that C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-12.0.2.10-hotspot\lib doesn't work. I think you should not be putting external jars at that location. You should put them at a different location and reference it from there.